# plot a line from a dict with two values for each key

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, line, stock

hey you can look down here to see my code, iam trying to plot dict_merged so that each value be a trend line or just points.

```py
path = r"C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\migdal\2017 stocks.csv"
import csv
import random

NUM_OF_STOCKS = 5

with open(path , "r") as stocks:
    reader = csv.DictReader(stocks)
    next(reader)
    names = []
    for i in reader:  # Saves all stocks' names
        if i["Name"] not in names:
            names.append(i["Name"])
    stocks.seek(0)
    next(reader)
    stocks_dict = dict()
    random_names = sorted(random.sample(names, NUM_OF_STOCKS))  # Picks 5 stocks randomly
    index = 0
    flag = False
    for i in reader:  # Creating dict of dates and change% for random names
        if i["Name"] == random_names[index]:
            flag = True
            if i["ï»¿date"] in stocks_dict:
                stocks_dict[i["ï»¿date"]].append(i["Change %"])
            else:
                stocks_dict[i["ï»¿date"]] = [i["Change %"]]
            continue
        if flag and i["Name"] != random_names[index]:
            index += 1
            flag = False
        if index == NUM_OF_STOCKS:
            break
    print(stocks_dict)
    for date in stocks_dict:  # Runs over all dates
        sum = 0
        for value in stocks_dict[date]:  # Runs over NUM_OF_STOCKS values of each key
            cur_val = value.replace('%', '')
            sum += float(cur_val)
        stocks_dict[date].append(str('{:.2f}'.format(sum / NUM_OF_STOCKS)) + '%')
    print(stocks_dict)
    fund = dict()
    for key, value in stocks_dict.items():
        fund.update({key:value[5]})
    path2 = r"C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\migdal\Book4.csv"
    with open(path2 , "r" , encoding ="utf-8") as sp:
        r = csv.reader(sp, delimiter=',')
        dict_s = dict()
        for i in r:
            dict_s.update(r)
    dict_merged = {}
    for key in dict_s.keys():
        dict_merged[key] = [fund[key],dict_s[key]]
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: hey you can look down here to see my code, iam trying to plot dict_merged so that each value be a trend line or just points.